# How to add ISSN in arxiv submission?

Tags: arxiv

The preprint version of my article has been already published in arXiv. Now I want to add the ISSN of the journal that published my publication. Unfortunately, they don't provide any doi. Could you please explain how to add ISSN to an arXiv preprint? Is it like -> Edit journal ref -> Report number:?

Comment: Yes, click on "replace" and update the information. You may need to reupload the files, though.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arXiv user support team replied this:

> There is no present metadata element for an ISBN (though this may be
> included within the new data model, which would be instituted in the
> coming years), and further, there is no standard location to indicate
> such. DOI and Journal-ref should be reported in those fields, and an
> ISBN number could be part of a Journal-ref if the complete workshop is
> issuing page numbers and DOI.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the journal ref seems the right tool for the job, from the description on https://arxiv.org/help/jref . But I'd say the journal name is enough (as they suggest on the page I linked) and the ISSN provides little additional information.

Have you tried adding one with the memnu entries you stated in your question? Does it work?

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply. I did not try those steps, as my collaborators are reputed professors. I wanted to be sure at first. And the arxiv community told us that for a single paper, we can not add the ISSN number. Only the organizers can do that for their complete submission.